# Snowflake Lead Function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a question about the use of the `lead` function within Snowflake.

Let's say I have a text field of `'881885895.1636104601'`. When I run the `lead` function (assume this number repeats and returns this from the `lead` result), I noticed that the output gets trimmed/truncated to `'881885895.16361'`.

Does anyone know why this is the case, or has seen this strange behavior before?

Comment: What you _see_ in your particular SQL client might be truncated, but this does not necessarily mean that precision has been lost.

Comment: Please show some sample data and a sample query so we can play with it, and desired results

Comment: It is most likely implicit conversion. Example provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with LEAD() function, it happens when you implicitly casting string to number.

See the example below:

```
select '881885895.1636104601'::double;
+--------------------------------+
| '881885895.1636104601'::DOUBLE |
|--------------------------------|
|                881885895.16361 |
+--------------------------------+
```

When users casting string to number implicitly, Snowflake will default to NUMBER(18,5).

If you need more scale and precision, you need to cast explicitly.

```
select '881885895.1636104601'::number(38,10);
+---------------------------------------+
| '881885895.1636104601'::NUMBER(38,10) |
|---------------------------------------|
|                  881885895.1636104601 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using default value that has different data type causes an implicit conversion. An example to reporduce the case:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT '881885895.1636104601' AS COL, 1 AS ID
    UNION ALL SELECT '881885895.1636104601' AS COL, 2 AS ID
)
SELECT *, LEAD(col,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY ID)
FROM cte;
-- Output
-- 881885895.1636104601    vs 881885895.16361

DESCRIBE RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
-- name      col
-- col       VARCHAR(20)
-- lead      NUMBER(18,5)
```

[image]

---

By matching the data type the output is as intended:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT '881885895.1636104601' AS COL, 1 AS ID
    UNION ALL SELECT '881885895.1636104601' AS COL, 2 AS ID
)
SELECT *, LEAD(col,1,'0') OVER(ORDER BY ID)
FROM cte;
```

[image]